# Defer Web Install Banner

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

According to [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/increasing-engagement-with-app-install-banners-in-chrome-for-android?hl=en) it is possible to defer the Web App Install banner, however I have only been able to cancel it completely.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function(e) {
  console.log('beforeinstallprompt Event fired');
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

One use case is to defer the prompt until later in the page lifecycle, for example just after a user has performed an action, or hit the bottom of the page (something to indicate that they are engaging with your site).

How is it possible to defer the web-app banner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/app-install-banners/advanced?hl=en), if it can help you.

Here is the complete code that use in deferring the Prompt.

```
var deferredPrompt;

window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function(e) {
  console.log('beforeinstallprompt Event fired');
  e.preventDefault();

  // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
  deferredPrompt = e;

  return false;
});

btnSave.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if(deferredPrompt !== undefined) {
    // The user has had a postive interaction with our app and Chrome
    // has tried to prompt previously, so let's show the prompt.
    deferredPrompt.prompt();

    // Follow what the user has done with the prompt.
    deferredPrompt.userChoice.then(function(choiceResult) {

      console.log(choiceResult.outcome);

      if(choiceResult.outcome == 'dismissed') {
        console.log('User cancelled home screen install');
      }
      else {
        console.log('User added to home screen');
      }

      // We no longer need the prompt.  Clear it up.
      deferredPrompt = null;
    });
  }
});
```

For more information, check also this [link](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/app-install-banner/deferred-banner/).

Comment: Yeah, it should be `if (deferredPrompt)` as that value becomes `null` when user clicks custom button

Comment: I tried the same code but it is giving me error that "The page must call beforeinstallpromptevent.prompt() to show the banner." What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

I use Chrome 76 and couldn't get it work with the other (older) answers. I took a look in the Chrome java script debugger and found out that the following needs to be used instead:

```
var deferredPrompt;

$(window).on('beforeinstallprompt', function(e) {
    console.log('beforeinstallprompt Event fired');
    e.preventDefault();

    // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
    deferredPrompt = e.originalEvent;

    return false;
});
```

*edit:
To get the event via e.originalEvent is only needed when jquery is used to register the event.